# Can OpenWhisk trigger Docker actions in my Bluemix registry?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I  pushed my Docker image to my Bluemix registry; I ran the container on Bluemix just fine; I have also set up a skeleton OpenWhisk rule which triggers a sample Python action but wish to trigger the image in my Bluemix registry as the action.

But, as far as I  can see from the OpenWhisk documents, it is only possible to trigger Docker actions hosted on Docker Hub. (Per the `wsk idk install docker` skeleton).

Can OpenWhisk trigger Docker actions in my Bluemix registry?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible.

OpenWhisk can only create Actions from Docker images stored in the external Docker Hub registry.

Comment: thanks for the info. I'd tick this as the right answer except that hopefully at some future date it will become the wrong answer ;-) when OpenWhisk is no longer "Experimental" and is available in the UK Region.

Comment: When that happens, I'll add the new answer and you can re-select that one.